# Optimized Sequencing Tasks with Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have 50 tasks that I am looking to sequence over 3 weeks (15 days) using Python. Is it possible to output a list of every combination that is possible? I am trying to take inputs and prioritize them to show if you do X first, then you'll get Y. What is the most flexible solution to offer users the ability to interact with the data and re-order where needed

Comment: The number of combinations is 3e+64. There can't be any reason to list that many combinations. Could you revise your question to say what your goal is? If it's a matter of prioritizing tasks, people may be able to direct you toward possible solutions, but they need more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to find a solution to offer my team an interactive experience to be able to say "if we reorder this, what does it effect?"  My idea was to create a number of scenarios so in reality you're really just flipping inbetween scenarios but it looks like youre reordering.